# how to build a VSNET 2008 application using MSBUILD with Administrator rights

Tags: c#, msbuild, com-interop, uac

I need to build a .NET application(x86) remotely using MSBuild. 
My application basically has to register for the COM Interop in 64bit Windows 7 system
However since i'm running into some problems due to UAC.

I need to elevate the default permission of MSBuild to Administrator.
How do i do this? How can i remotely open a VSNET Command prompt with Administrative privileges. ?

I'm presently running with the switch in this line

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5>MsBuild SolutionPath\Solution.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="x86"
```

Or

Is there an efficient alternative ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`runas` command cannot run without manually entering password. Try to use `psexec` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553 by Mark Russinovich. It can run program on remote PC but also can run at local PC as specified user.

Answer (score 0):

use `runas` command. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx

Comment: Also right clicking on the Command Prompt shortcut > `Run as administrator` should do

Comment: @KMoraz, I dont want to manually intervene so this option wont do any good :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disable UAC if you don't need it. [Use regedit to disable it completely](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/windows-7/disable-modify-uac-notification-in-windows-7/). Disabling UAC using "UAC slider" to "do not notify" was not helpful in my case.